# does XMLDOMNodePtr::get_text() needs to be deallocated explicitly?

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++

Greetings,

Would like to know if we need to explicitly free the string allocated by a xmldomnodeptr using it's get_text()

i.e.

```
    IXMLDOMNodePtr pNode;
    /*some code*/
    BSTR sValue;
    pNode->get_text(&sValue);
    /*Should I do this?*/
    SysFreeString(sValue);
```

I cannot see any documentation stating the same, so I'm assuming we need to do explicit deallocation sysfreestring. But, Just need to be double sure :)

Thanks in advance.

Samrat Patil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. You will have to free the string.

```
BSTR bstrItemText = NULL;
pIDOMNode->get_text(&bstrItemText); //Discl: return value is not checked here...
if(bstrItemText)
 {
     ::SysFreeString(bstrItemText);
     bstrItemText = NULL;
 }
```